# Track won't play even if track is streamable

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm using the soundcloud API and so far it was working fine until I hit this track:
https://soundcloud.com/katyperryofficial/roar

I don't know what's wrong with this track but it really wouldn't play. I can get all info of it just not the stream part. I checked chrome network tab and it gives me this. It just cancels without any error:

```
Name                     Method  Status      Type   Initiator   Size  Time
stream?consumer_key=###  GET     (canceled)  Other              13B   1.02s
```

Any ideas? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundcloud devs made some changes in their code, and i don't know why, they are switching back to rtmp protocol.

Even the response said that track is streamable it can't be streamed with a regular stream_url.

After some digging in dev tools, i've noticed that some tracks use rtmp protocol instead of http/https

Anyway, you can find the streams of the track on:
`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TrackID/streams?consumer_key=XXX`

from here, you're on your own. from my research, only flash (why?) can play rtmp streams.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that info. How did you or how do I determine if a track is RTMP or not?

Comment: get the `/streams` then try to play `stream_url`, if it throws an error, try to play rtmp stream.

Comment: Aaahh. I thought they'd like return some boolean saying if it's rtmp or http or something. Is this related to this problem https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1 ?

Comment: it looks like it. but still, it's a flash fallback for rtmp. if users are using flashblock or flash it's not installed, it will not work.

Comment: Yeah. And I guess we'd have a hard time making it work for mobile and the there's iPhone who doesn't have flash.